# Getting the last comments from all the posts

Tags: cakephp

So, I have a system with users, users have posts and posts have comments. Everything is well linked with the models.

What I'ld like to do is getting all the last comments from all the posts of one specific user.

And I'm a bit stuck. Any ideas ?

Comment: Please post the database schema first!

Comment: Please show the relationships of model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this from `UsersController` (not tested):

```
$comments = $this->User->Post->Comment->find('all', array(
    'recursive' = 1,
    'limit' => 4,
    'order' => array('Comment.created' => 'DESC'),
    'conditions' => array('Post.user_id' => $id_user)
));
```

You can change `recursive` to `2` if you need to retrieve `User` as well.

Comment: Yep, that seems to works (weird I was trying basically the same thing without success :/ ). Anyway, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$this->User->Behaviors->load('Containable');
$this->User->contain(array(
    'Post' => array(
        'order' => array('Post.created' => 'DESC'),
        'Comment' => array(
            'limit' => 4,
            'order' => array('Comment.created' => 'DESC')
        )
    )
));
$rs = $this->User->read(null, $id_user);
$this->User->Behaviors->unload('Containable');
```

Your result is on **$rs** variable.

Reference:

- [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not exactly what I want, would too easy :p No, what I want is getting all the comments from all the posts of a user, sort them by date and get the 4th last. Not the lasts of one post but the last from all the posts.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I did, just change the limit to 4 and order Post too (you have not specified in the question). What's wrong with the result?

Comment: Let's imagine 2 posts like that https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1829557/Sans-titre-1.jpg With your solution, the array with the comments would look like this : Comment 2, Comment 1, Comment 4, Comment 3. What I'ld like is that the array with the comments looking like that : Comment 4, Comment 2, Comment 3, Comment 1.